# How to get backup file or file conversion

Tags: google-drive-api, file-conversion, backups

I had uploaded my web design files to the google drive. Those files were with extenstions .html,.css and.js, Those files had been uploaded successfully to the google drive. Today, I was trying to download those files and come to know that all files had been stored as an extension .docx. Now I don't have any other backups of my source file. I want source code of all my webdesigns. How can I get them? In file properties, its showing me file type .docx

Comment: they where probably uploaded with conversion on. Now they are converted to .docx. You will probably have to manually convert them back some how. Google drive doesn't have a convert download option.

Comment: I couldn't find any way to covert those files. If anybody know, how to bring it back, it would be great.